# Get Multiple Rows in PHP / MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to pull the image link for 10 different rows based on ids in an array. It seems to break when the query is in the loop..Any ideas how i can accomplish this?

```
$array = array(54, 319, 342, 298, 281, 190,178,158,138,7);


$shuffleKeys = array_keys($array);
shuffle($shuffleKeys);
$newArray = array();
foreach($shuffleKeys as $key) {
    $newArray[$key] = $array[$key];
}


for($i=0;$i<=count($newArray);$i++){

    $query = "SELECT logoName,logoImageLink, logoImageLink2, countryImg, logoArtist, afterText, country FROM logos WHERE id = $array($i)     ";
    $result = mysql_query($query);


    /* fetch rows in reverse order */
    for ($i = mysql_num_rows($result) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    if (!mysql_data_seek($result, $i)) {
        echo "Cannot seek to row $i: " . mysql_error() . "\n";
        continue;
    }

    if (!($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) {
        continue;
    }

    $imageLink = $row['logoImageLink'];

    echo "<li class=\".$array($i).\" ><img src=\".$imageLink.\" /></li>";
}
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [MySQL IN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) clause and do this in a single select.

```
$ids = join(',',$newArray);  
$query = "SELECT logoName,logoImageLink, logoImageLink2, countryImg, logoArtist, afterText, country FROM logos WHERE id IN ($ids)";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $imageLink = $row['logoImageLink'];

     echo "<li><img src=\"$imageLink\"/></li>";
}
```

Comment: Is this then like creating a multli level array? Or how do I get the logoImageLink for id 342 then 190 etc?

Comment: okay..i have seen this around a little bit. But i'm still a bit confused on how it works... so if i want to say just print the logoImageLink for each id in the array, how can i do that with whats given? If I can see that I think i got it. thx for your help.

Comment: $row is an array containing all the returned fields, you can use it the exact way you were in your question.